# Script Editor: Wait for Safari to finish loading. My JavaScript method not working

Tags: javascript, safari, applescript

I'm trying to execute a simple command: load URL1, wait for Safari to finish loading URL1, then load URL2 in the same tab. For some reason, the code below loads URL1 and then stops. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell window 1
        tell current tab
            set URL to "https://google.com"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

tell application "Safari"
    tell window 1 to repeat
        do JavaScript "document.readyState"
        if the result = "complete" then exit repeat
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
end tell

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell window 1
        tell current tab
            set URL to "https://apple.com"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow your browser to **Allow Javascript from Apple Events**.  First you enable **Show Develop menu in menu bar** then you click on **Allow Javascript from Apple Events** in the Develop menu of the browser

[image: Show Develop menu in menu bar]
[image: Allow Javascript from Apple Events]

Updated version (I added some log statements so you can see the page is loaded before the second one is opened):

```
set URL1 to "https://google.com"
set URL2 to "https://apple.com"
set done to false

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    
    set currentTab to current tab of window 1
    set URL of currentTab to URL1
    
    repeat until (done is true)
        log done
        if (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in currentTab) is "complete" then
            log (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in currentTab)
            set done to true
        end if
    end repeat
   
    log done

    if done then
        tell currentTab
            set URL to URL2
        end tell
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: Sorry, but your code is not working right. I just tested it: it opens two tabs automatically, with the second tab loading URL2 before the first tab finishes loading URL1. My goal: After URL1 finishes loading, I need URL2 to load **in the same tab**.

Comment: check the updated version

Answer (score 0):

I wrote in the past following script for this task. It is designed for webpages with **/html** tag at end of its source. On many web pages, the /html tag is **not a continuous word** and spans on multiple paragraphs. My handler works with them too, unlike many provided on the net. Also, I prefer to use **open location** command to load websites. You can replace it if need:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate -- optional
    try
        close (current tab of window 1) -- optional, if you won't grow additional tabs
    end try
    open location "https://google.com"
    my waitSafariWebPageLoading(10) -- maximum seconds to wait = 10 seconds
    if result is true then set googleHTML to (source of document 1)
    close (current tab of window 1) -- optional, if you won't grow additional tabs
    open location "https://apple.com"
    my waitSafariWebPageLoading(10) -- maximum seconds to wait = 10 seconds
    if result is true then set appleHTML to (source of document 1)
end tell
return {googleHTML, appleHTML}

-- Safari.app: Pause a Script until a Web Page has Loaded
on waitSafariWebPageLoading(loadingWaitMaximumSeconds as integer)
    set lineChangingChars to {linefeed, return, character id 11, character id 12, character id 133, character id 8232, character id 8233}
    set {ATID, htmlEnding} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, ""}
    tell application "Safari"
        repeat 100 * loadingWaitMaximumSeconds times -- wait seconds
            delay 0.1
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"<", ">"}
            try
                copy text item -2 of (get source of front document) to htmlEnding
            end try
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to lineChangingChars
            set htmlEnding to text items of htmlEnding
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
            set htmlEnding to "<" & htmlEnding & ">"
            if htmlEnding is "</html>" then exit repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ATID
    if htmlEnding is "</html>" then return true
    display notification "The webpage loading failed"
    return false
end waitSafariWebPageLoading
```

The **mostly stable** handler I wrote, uses GUI scripting. It works with any webpage and it is simpler as well:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    make new document with properties {URL:"https://www.macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=19262"}
    my waitSafariWebPageLoading()
    display dialog "The webpage is fully loaded now."
end tell

on waitSafariWebPageLoading()
    tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Safari"
        repeat until (UI element "Reload this page" of group 3 of toolbar 1 of window 1 exists) or (UI element "Reload this page" of group 2 of toolbar 1 of window 1 exists)
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
    end tell
end waitSafariWebPageLoading
```